# Programmatically get the list of versions from appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'd like to get a list of deployed versions from appengine, either from the remote API or via appcfg.py. I can't seem to find any way to do it, certainly not a documented way. Does anyone know of any way to do this (even undocumented)?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can list deployed versions in the admin console under "Admin Logs". Short of screen-scraping this page, there's no way to access this data programmatically.

You can submit this as an enhancement request to the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this by copying some of the RPC code from appcfg.py into my application.  I posted up [this gist](https://gist.github.com/MattFaus/7275456) that goes into detail on how to do this, but I will repeat them here for posterity.

1. [Install the python API client](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation#appengine). This will give you the OAuth2 and httplib2 libraries you need to interact with Google's RPC servers from within your application.
2. Copy this file from the GAE SDK installed on your development machine: `google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc_httplib2.py` into your GAE webapp.
3. Obtain a refresh token by executing `appcfg.py list_versions . --oauth2` from your local machine.  This will open a browser so you can login to your Google Account.  Then, you can find the `refresh_token` in ~/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens
4. Modify and run the following code inside of a web handler:

Enjoy.

```
from third_party.google_api_python_client import appengine_rpc_httplib2

# Not-so-secret IDs cribbed from appcfg.py
# https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py#144
APPCFG_CLIENT_ID = '550516889912.apps.googleusercontent.com'
APPCFG_CLIENT_NOTSOSECRET = 'ykPq-0UYfKNprLRjVx1hBBar'
APPCFG_SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appengine.admin']

source = (APPCFG_CLIENT_ID,
            APPCFG_CLIENT_NOTSOSECRET,
            APPCFG_SCOPES,
            None)

rpc_server = appengine_rpc_httplib2.HttpRpcServerOauth2(
    'appengine.google.com',
    # NOTE: Here's there the refresh token is used
    "your OAuth2 refresh token goes here",
    "appcfg_py/1.8.3 Darwin/12.5.0 Python/2.7.2.final.0",
    source,
    host_override=None,
    save_cookies=False,
    auth_tries=1,
    account_type='HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE',
    secure=True,
    ignore_certs=False)

# NOTE: You must insert the correct app_id here, too
response = rpc_server.Send('/api/versions/list', app_id="khan-academy")

# The response is in YAML format
parsed_response = yaml.safe_load(response)
if not parsed_response:
    return None
else:
    return parsed_response
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Google has recently released a `get_versions()` function in the  `google.appengine.api.modules` package.  I recommend using that over the hack I implemented in my other answer.

Read more at:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/functions

Comment: Right! But, unless I missed something, it's impossible to use that from outside the GAE infrastructure. I'm writing a deployment script that would shut down previous versions of manual scaling modules, and I can't use these Python API from a local machine / deployment server...