# Getting notifications on Google App Engine when an app version is made the default version

Tags: google-app-engine, screen-scraping, web-scraping

**Background**

I'd like to set up a system that notifies team members whenever an app version is made the default version on Google App Engine's admin console. The reason is to keep all developers updated when a version is changed to default. And this notification should not be suppressable by developers to ensure that no notifications are missed.

When I asked Google support about any such notification, they said none existed and added a suggestion to feature request #4260111 to provide a monitoring API.

In Google App Engine's admin console for a particular application, there is a section called Admin Logs. The Admin Logs can be filtered by event "Verson Made Default" to get log lines for every time an app version has been made the default version in production. These logs cannot be suppressed, which is good for my purpose.

Here is what a log line looks like.

```
Date                  Administrator      Event                      Result
2012-06-14 12:30:51   a@example.com      Set the default version    version=123.timestamp
```

The URL these logs lines are available at has the form:

```
http://appengine.google.com/adminlogs?app_id=s%7Esome_app_id&type=version_made_default&limit=20
```

A response to a similar question on SO indicates that currently the only solution now is to scrape the page at the URL above. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8084798/888759

**Question:**

To view the admin logs at the URL above, the admin has to be logged in. How can I scrape this page behind a Google App Engine admin console login wall?

How would a scraping script authenticate to Google App Engine's admin console?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be inspecting the HTTP 'Host' header. It *could* eventually go from `<appversion>.<appid>.appspot.com` to `<appid>.appspot.com` or your custom DNS hostname.

Anyway I would prefer something at the API level.